# Can not view images with spaces in its name

Tags: php, html, image, echo, jpeg

i cant view images with spaces in its name ex: Google Twitter.JPG is not loading and its name is changed to Google%20Twitter.JPG after the PHP echo method .

```
<image width=150px height = 100px src="upload/profiles/<?php echo trim($image); ?> >
```

Comment: Spaces are being printed as %20 in urls, that's normal.

Comment: so why my image is not loaded since its normal ?

Comment: and how to override this issue

Comment: aren't you missing a quote (") character at the end of your link?

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your markup.

Change `<image width=150px...`

to

`<img width=150px...`

Answer (score 0):

This is a requirement in W3 Standards

From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp :

> URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

You should rename your images, and replace the spaces with either dashes `-` or underscores `_`

As pointed out in comments, you are missing a quote, and have some errors in your line. `image` should be `img` and your height and width attributes should be in quotes with no spaces.

```
<img width="150px" height="100px" src="upload/profiles/<?php echo trim($image);?>" />
```

Comment: but the image name in my file directory is "Google Twitter.JPG" as i have uploaded it , how can i override this issue and replace the %20

Comment: You should rename your images in your FTP software so they don't have any spaces. Then you'll need to re-link the filenames in your code or CMS, whichever you are using.

Comment: so is there any php method can replace $string spaces into any other symbol ex:(" - , _ , +) ?

Comment: Yes you can use `preg_replace` to replace characters in a PHP variable, but you really need to change your image filenames. That's the most ideal solution.

Comment: @user2319470 Do you even try to search things such as "replace part of a string in php" on any search engine before asking ?

Comment: Try the re-written line I've provided first. Your images may not have been showing because of the errors in the line.